# When a topic is created on Stackoverflow, does a new html file get created or is it one file that gets changed based on the topic the user picks?

Tags: html, database, web, forum

Specifically, when I create a new question and it is titled "My question," in the url bar it is going to send me to something like: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/My_question". Does this mean that a new file called "My question" was created or is this question placed in a database as an object and then displayed on a single template for all questions? Thank you.

Comment: No new file is created, just a db entry which is referenced via the ID in the URL. Also this questions belongs over on Meta

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and for your help.

Comment: This question belongs on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), which is a site where you ask questions about this site.

Comment: I was using Stackoverflow as more of an example. Any type of site such as Reddit, Github, etc... that allows for users to create new content to be displayed is what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the site technically works, but it's probably something like this:

Stack Overflow uses that question id you see in the URL (41493753 in this case), looks that number up in a database a loads all the detail information, there's not an actual file for every question in the server, it's probably more like a QuestionDetail template page that is filled dynamically.